# Qual o risco desse injection?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

Fala pessoal, qual risco eu correria se alguém quisesse dar um injection nesse exemplo:

```
$valorGet = $_GET["valor"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE caminho = '$valorGet'";
```

Minha dúvida é, o cara consegue deletar (DELETE) ou inserir (INSERT) algo no meu banco? Ou apenas dar um outro tipo de SELECT?

Existe a necessidade de fazer um antijection com PDO nesse caso para aumentar a segurança?

Comment: Eu sei que da pra fazer um injection, mas minha pergunta foi se o meu banco corre algum risco, pois estou fazendo só um SELECT, ele teria como dar um DELETE ou INSERT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **N** maneiras de inserir dados, apagar, unir tabelas, etc. Numa query simples como essa... Aqui um exemplo clássico e básico para ignorar o caminho:

```
$valorGet = "';DELETE FROM tabela WHERE 1=1;-- ";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE caminho = '$valorGet'";
```

neste caso a estrutura receberia:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE caminho = 'aqui entra o valor injetado: (';INSERT INTO tabela VALUES ('1','2','3','4');-- )'";
```

Cuja a saída seria algo assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE caminho = '';DELETE FROM tabela WHERE 1=1;--";
```

Comment: Então, mas o cara só daria um SELECT diferente, ele não deletaria nada, não?

Comment: Dá pra deletar também, vou editar a pergunta para você ver.

Comment: Era isso, valeu!

Answer (score 3):

Sim, existe o risco de alguém deletar todo o seu banco ao explorar essa vulnerabilidade. A solução não passa necessariamente por PDO, e sim por *prepared statements*, que você consegue usar tanto com PDO quanto com mysqli. Note que não basta trocar o driver de conexão ao banco para resolver o problema, você precisa parametrizar a query como explicado em [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php).

Comment: Então, mas o cara só daria um SELECT diferente, ele não deletaria nada, não?

Comment: Como eu disse, tem sim o risco de ele deletar.